# Navigation Drawer switching Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am having this problem when working with Navigation Drawer and Activities instead of Fragments. Everything runs smooth, but when i initialize the Drawer (DrawerHome) I hit an screen which is not neither of my Activities. When I set default to be any of the Activities, the executions runs into loop and never stops. I am just wondering if it is possible to achieve this or I must go and user Fragments and only one Activity.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Really appreciate.

Comment: If your Navigation Drawer only opens other Activities, it's kind of defeating the purpose of using one, and a simple Menu might be more appropriate. That said, it is possible, but we'd have to see code to remedy your situation.

Comment: Well, I guess I was following the androidhive tutorial (http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and instead of fragments i used activities. I guess I should switch to Simple Menu and I will not have the abovementioned problem ? @mikeM.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like when one of your Activities loads, a nav drawer item is auto-selected, and starting up another Activity, ad infinitum. If you've only two Activities, something like a Menu, ActionBar buttons, our even inline Buttons would be preferable. If you want to keep the nav drawer, Fragments would be the way to go.

Comment: The Only reason why I have switched was the easiness of implementing the stuff I wanted into Activities. Actually, never tried fragments before and most of things I implemented I guess are not as straighforward as when implemented with Activities.

Comment: Fragments are pretty easy. You can treat them kinda like mini-Activities, with some minor differences. E.g., your View setups take place in `onCreateView()` instead of `onCreate()`, the Fragments have to have a parent Activity, etc. Just play around with them. If you understand Activities, it's just a few more things to learn. You'll get the hang of it.

Comment: I guess that is my chance and try to fix the things by using Fragments. I appreciate your effor and help. Thank you